# Start and end Windows programs CONDITIONALLY?

Tags: windows-7

I have a controller mapping program I want to use all the time EXCEPT when playing games. I have mapped certain keys which open windows flip view. When playing games - TES V Skyrim - the mapper is still active and I would like to end/pause the program and be able to restart/unpause after. I don't know if there were any programs that can manage other programs runtime according to certain conditions.

Comment: Is it okay to force quit it when you start TES V Skyrim and restart it when you are done? It sounds like it but I just wanted to confirm

Comment: I am assuming that you have already set it to a lower priority than Skyrim and still want it gone-gone?

Comment: Out of curiosity what controller mapping program do you use?

Comment: The program I use is Keysticks.  I have not tried setting it to a lower priority yet - would this in theory allow skyrim's controls to override keysticks mapping?  Would I have to set the priority each time I start skyrim?  And yes it is ok to force quit Keysticks when I start Skyrim and restart it when I'm done as long as it is all automatic and does not interfere with the overall flow of using the controller.  Thanks.